# Is there any issues to have `end` as a method name?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a RoR project, and I want to know if I can use `end` as a method name. It seems to work fine, but I would like to know if this method will bring any issues in the future. I tried and it works:

```
class Dany
  def end
    puts 'Hola'
  end
end
```

and this is the output:

```
Dany.new.end # => Hola
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use a keyword as a method name, but as long as you disambiguate the token as a method call, you can use it. It is not practical though.

```
Dany.new.instance_eval{self.end} # => Hola
Dany.new.send(:end)              # => Hola
Dany.new.method(:end).call       # => Hola
Dany.new.instance_eval{end}      # => syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

The usual disambiguation using `()` does not seem to work for this case, making it complicated.

```
Dany.new.instance_eval{end()}    # => syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

Answer (score 8):

Ruby let's you do this, but you're going to run into all sorts of issues.

```
# end.rb
class Dany

  def end
    puts "Hola"
  end

  def other
    end  # should puts Hola
  end
end
```

Instead, you will get

> end.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

---

**Bottom line:** don't do this. Don't use any [keywords](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) as a method name.

Comment: `loop` is not a keyword, it's a private instance method of `Kernel`. If it *were* a keyword, you couldn't override it since you can only override methods in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag; I removed the loop example.